# Raspberry pi 400 no sound over HDMI

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, audio, hdmi

I bought a Raspberry Pi 400 to connect it to my old TV (Telefunken) and make it a smart TV. I installed the latest Raspberry Pi OS, and everything works EXCEPT the sound. I connected the TV by the official Raspberry HDMI cable, and I have the official charger. If I connect the Raspberry Pi to another old Sony TV everything works fine. Also If I connect my laptop (Win 10) to the Telefunken Tv, everything works.

I tried everything I found on the internet, every possible permutations of the options in the config.txt file. (hdmi_group, hdmi_drive=2, etc.) When I go to raspi-config, and enter Audio options, it blinks one, and goes back. So I cannot even get to the Audio options. I use the HDMI 0 port. It seems like a hardware problem in Raspberry Pi.

Do you have any ide what I could try?

Comment: *It seems like a hardware problem in Raspberry Pi* - why? the pi works with a different TV? the issue seems more like *interoperability* between the Pi and the Telefuken

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you have any idea what could I do about it to make it work?

Comment: try `hdmi_safe=1`

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried it, and unfortunately it did not help. I understand that Telefunken is not a popular brand, but it has to be a way to make it work, since it works fine with my Windows 10 laptop. I tried every HDMI port both on TV and on Raspberry.

Comment: if every combination of display / device works except for Pi / Telefunken then there are two possibilities - some incompatibility between the pi and telfunken or something wrong with the cable that causes incompatibility between the pi and telefunken - there is no indication that the pi has two faulty HDMI ports - the only way to determine if that is the case is to try another pi 400 - have you tried using SSH to login to the pi and debugging using `tvservice` for example to see what's going on?

Comment: That's a great idea, but when I try to run tvservice it says "tvservice is not supported when using the vc4-kms-v3d driver". Do this mean I am using the wrong driver?

Comment: You could comment out the line that loads `vc4-kms-v3d` for the purposes of debugging

Comment: @Bravo A very strange thing happened. When I commented out the ```dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d``` line, the TV audio was found by Raspberry Pi, and it works! BUT now I have very poor video performance, basically every video lags. I wonder what this vc4-kms-v3d does, and why does it have any affect on audio. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If I set ```dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d``` both audio and video works well. This is the "fake kms mode", and this is the legacy mode. I still don't understand why doesn't it work with the normal kms mode.

Comment: that is odd - yet another raspberry pi foundation *testing* fail perhaps - anyway, `tvservice` should now be able to tell you some details about the HDMI connection that may be useful when trying to figure out why this one TV doesn't work properly